# Perl XML::DOM parser with entity inside the attribute

Tags: xml, parsing

When i parse an XML using XML::DOM, the entity present inside the attribute was moved outside the tag.

```
use XML::DOM;
my $parser = new XML::DOM::Parser;
my $doc = $parser->parsefile("demo.xml");
print $doc->toString;
```

Sample demo XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE candy SYSTEM "demo.dtd">
<candy>
   <product id="1">Mints</product>
   <product id="xx&ast;yy">Chocolate</product>
   <product id="3">Circus Peanuts</product>
</candy>
```

But in the output, "*" entity present in the second product attribute id was moved outside the tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE candy SYSTEM "demo.dtd">
<candy>
  <product id="1">Mints</product>
  &ast;<product id="xxyy">Chocolate</product>
  <product id="3">Circus Peanuts</product>
</candy>
```

I need the XML as it's.

Answer (score 0):

Use junk * instead of ast entity, Entity can't be parsed by perl